# Google OAuth Login in DRF application raise Invalid token type

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-allauth, dj-rest-auth

I had implemented Google OAuth in my DRF application using [all-auth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) and [dj-rest-auth](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth), but for some reason stop working.

Traceback shows the JWT, but for some reason, allauth raise this

```
  raise DecodeError(f"Invalid token type. Token must be a {bytes}")
```

[Traceback_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3C2u.png)

[Traceback_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8eyq.png)

I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@aaron-ak/django-rest-framework-drf-with-google-oauth-server-side-flow-using-dj-auth-and-django-allauth-126dcd20374b) but couldn't reproduce the scenario.

The code is at this [PR](https://github.com/theusindabike/trombei-api/pull/4)

Does anyone have the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded dj-rest-auth to version 2.2.7 and all go live again