# OAuth2Error at /auth/google/ Invalid id_token f"Invalid token type. Token must be a {bytes}")

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-allauth, dj-rest-auth

According to the [dj-rest-auth Social Auth steps](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#social-authentication-optional), I have added all the necessary apps in the `INSTALLED_APPS` section

I want to login with Google, so under the [Google steps](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#social-authentication-optional), I have added the google provider, created the view and added the URL.

On my frontend, after login, I get this

```
email: "email@gmail.com"
firstName: "name"
id: "10xx"
idToken: "eyJhbGciOiJSU-xxx"
lastName: "name"
name: "name"
photoUrl: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AC-xxx"
provider: "GOOGLE"
```

I listen to the AuthState changes, and make a payload request to the backend as

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
      const token = user.idToken;
      this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/auth/google/', {
        access_token: token
      }).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
    });
  }
```

Doing the above throws the error:

```
OAuth2Error at /auth/google/
Invalid id_token
```

"Ah, but why aren't you sending in `id_token` but rather using `access_token`?", you ask.

According to the `OPTIONS` of the `/auth/google/` endpoint, these are expected

```
"actions": {
        "POST": {
            "access_token": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": false,
                "read_only": false,
                "label": "Access token"
            },
            "code": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": false,
                "read_only": false,
                "label": "Code"
            },
            "id_token": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": false,
                "read_only": false,
                "label": "Id token"
            }
        }
    }
```

But then doing

```
     this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/auth/google/', {
        id_token: token
      })
```

throws the error from the API as `"Incorrect input. access_token or code is required."`

I'm using

- dj-rest-auth==5.0.1
- django-allauth==0.58.2
- djangorestframework==3.14.0

Are there step not covered (won't be the first time) in the docs I'm missing?

Edit: [I do not wanna downgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75608141/1757321)

Comment: I assume you have a angular app and a backend in Django. If I understood it correctly, you are authenticating directly from your frontend, and is able to do so, but now you need a session in django. So you are grabbing this token  and posting to drf so you can also validate your Django app. I had to do this a few days ago, btw. Of that's your goal, we can investigate further.

Comment: Yes, Django as backend. Angular frontend. I'm *not* using the implicit code grant oauth2 approach. After login in Angular, I send token to dj-rest for validation

Answer (score 1):

Check that access_token and id_token are both in your request. use access_token and id_token in your POST request, if idToken is in fact the access token in your Angular code.

So add the line for id_token within your request

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/auth/google/', {
    access_token: accessToken,
    id_token: idToken
```

Comment: I only got `idToken` from the Google response. No `access_token` is/was given me.

Comment: set access token to idToken then. try: this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/auth/google/', {
        access_token: idToken
      })